# Apex Page with analytics:reportChart as part of Managed Package

Tags: apex, reporting, managed-package

I want to deploy a Apex Page that references a Report with analytics:reportChart in a Managed Package. The Report is also included in the Managed Package.

This issues arrises when the Apex Page needs to reference the reportID. The reportID will be different in every installed Managed Package. Any ideas on how I make this reference dynamic in the package?

This is what my code looks like:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Oe0000000aeYn" size="small">   </analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks